# Generating function of the terms congruent with $k\mod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, roots-of-unity

Given a generating function $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$, I've been trying to obtain the generating function of the terms $a_n$ such that $n\equiv k\mod m$. For $m=2$ this is easy enough:

$\begin{cases}f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n}x^{2n}+\sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\\
f(-x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n}x^{2n}-\sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\end{cases}\Rightarrow \sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n}x^{2n}=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\text{ and}\\\sum_{n\geq0}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$

How would it be generalized? I suspect you'd have to use roots of unity, but I am stumped as to how.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roots of unity filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega = \exp(2\pi i/d)$ a first $d$-th root of unity. Note that for $j < d$
$$ 
  f(\omega^j x) =\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \omega^{jn} x^n 
    = \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{dn + k} \omega^{jdn + jk} x^{dn+k}
    = \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \omega^{jk} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{dn + k} x^{dn+k}
$$
Fix $\ell < d$, then
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} \omega^{-j\ell} f(\omega^{j}x) = 
    \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\omega^{j(k-\ell)} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{dn + k} x^{dn+k} $$
Now $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\omega^{j(k-\ell)} = d\delta_{k,\ell}$, hence
$$ \frac 1d \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} \omega^{-j\ell} f(\omega^{j}x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{dn + \ell} x^{dn+\ell}$$